# want to add logger in my react hook while calling microservice from backend

Tags: javascript, reactjs, logging, react-redux, react-hooks

i am new to react and what i want to have logger in react hook app.i have to use logger while calling microservices from backend if showhow error occurs it stores in the logger.i have no idea to implement it. i have used redux-logger middleware.it gives me prev state next state but it does not give anything if error occurs
below is my index.js

```
const store=createStore(rootReducer,compose(applyMiddleware(thunk,logger)));

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following pattern locally on your actions/requests:

```
try {
  // your action/request
} catch (e) {
  logger(e) // your logger system
}
```

Comment: how to print that system logger later on

Answer (score 1):

you can try with error boundary

Comment: but error boundary is for error in ui.what i want it to have all error from microservices

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use **Loglevel** for logs in UI, and **Error Boundaries** in react to catch errors in your JavaScript application for the best result:

1. Loglevel: https://github.com/pimterry/loglevel
2. Error Boundaries: https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html